# Remove duplicate character in row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to make it possible to only type "x" (without the quotes) once in every row.
I would rather use data validation, but if that's not possible, I also could use VBA. I have tried several things with COUNTIF e.g. in data validation but I only can find out how to remove duplicates from columns not rows.

Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Can't you just simply use `conditional formatting` on your row using `COUNTIF($1:$1,"X")>1`. Works fine for me. That way an user is notified in a very visual way =)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following worksheet event macro. *(it uses `COUNTIF()`)*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, v As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, x As String
    
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    v = Target.Value
    Set rng = Target.EntireRow
    x = "x"
    
    If v <> x Then Exit Sub
    If wf.CountIf(rng, x) > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            MsgBox "Too many x"
            Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Gary's answer. There is no way to do this with just data validation and needs VBA with macros enabled to make it work exactly as described.

If you want to avoid VBA, you could start by restricting each cell to a drop down list of "x" or "".  Now use conditional formating to display a warning if counta is more than 1. The user must then manually delete the additional x's until the warming dissapears.

Comment: You may want to investigate the use of radio buttons. I believe as long as you don't assign any macros to the radio buttons, you can still save and use this as a normal xlsx file (not macro enables xlsm). Check out this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWcnbImuTc8